# How to group data separated by empty lines

Tags: python-3.x, list

I have a file that I wanted to group into list. The data are separated by empty lines. How to parse the data properly to get the needed output?

mydata.txt

```
introA
aboutA1
aboutA2
aboutA3
aboutA4

introB
aboutB1
aboutB2
aboutB3
aboutB4
```

Current Code:

```
with open("mydata.txt", "r") as f:
    data = [line.strip() for line in f if line.strip()]

print (data)
```

Current Output:

```
['introA', 'aboutA1', 'aboutA2', 'aboutA3', 'aboutA4', 'introB', 'aboutB1', 'aboutB2', 'aboutB3', 'aboutB4']
```

Needed Output:

```
"introA":['aboutA1', 'aboutA2', 'aboutA3', 'aboutA4',],
"introB":['aboutB1', 'aboutB2', 'aboutB3', 'aboutB4',],
```

Comment: It is not clear if the output is a dictionary. Is it?

Comment: dictionary output will also work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My approach is to first split lines by double new lines, which separate the blocks. Then within each block, split the lines:

```py
data = {}
with open("mydata.txt", "r") as stream:
    for block in stream.read().split("\n\n"):
        block = block.splitlines()
        key = block.pop(0)
        data[key] = block

print(data)
```

Output:

```
{'introA': ['aboutA1', 'aboutA2', 'aboutA3', 'aboutA4'], 'introB': ['aboutB1', 'aboutB2', 'aboutB3', 'aboutB4']}
```

Splitting text by double new line will give blocks of text such as

```py
'introA\naboutA1\naboutA2\naboutA3\naboutA4'
```

Then, the line

```py
        block = block.splitlines()
```

Will turn the block into a list of strings:

```py
['introA', 'aboutA1', 'aboutA2', 'aboutA3', 'aboutA4']
```

The `pop()` call will remove the first element in the list (`introA`) and assign it to the variable `key`. Then we build up the `data` dict by filling the key and the block.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple example

```
wordlist = {}
current_header = None

with open("mydata.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.rstrip('\n')

        if not line:
            current_header = None
            continue

        if not current_header:
            current_header = line
            wordlist[current_header] = []

        if current_header != line:
            wordlist[current_header].append(line)

print(wordlist)
```